# calculating cumulative distribution function with perl

Tags: perl

I got this code from one of my friends but because i did not work with perl, I don't know how it works. can you help me to understand it.

This file must get a file with some data that they shows delays and get the cumulative distribution function within the intervals.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


#print "Starting converter on file $ARGV[0]\n";

if ($#ARGV < 2 || $#ARGV > 3) {
    print "Usage: ac_hist_gen.pl <input file> <num intervals> <output file> [ <interval size> ]\n";
    exit(-1);
}

open(infile,"$ARGV[0]") || die "Couldn't open $ARGV[0] for reading.\n";
open(outfile,">$ARGV[2]") || die "Couldn't open $ARGV[2] for writing.\n";

for ($i=0; $i< 100 / $ARGV[1]; $i++) {
    $dist[$i] = 0;
    $acum[$i] = 0;
}

$max=0;



if ($#ARGV == 2) {

while (<infile>) {

    if ($_ > $max) {
    $max=$_;
    }    
}

$intsize = $max / $ARGV[1];
} else {
    $intsize= $ARGV[3];
}

close(infile);



#print "size is $numpkts, max is $max, div is $intsize , test is $test\n";


open(infile,"$ARGV[0]") || die "Couldn't open $ARGV[0] for reading.\n";

while (<infile>) {

    $val = int($_ / $intsize);

    if (($_ / $intsize) == $val) {
    $dist[$val-1]++;
    } else {
    $dist[$val]++;
    }

#  print "val is $val\n";


}

for ($i=0; $i< $ARGV[1]; $i++) {
    $limit = ($i+1) * $intsize;
    $acum[$i]+= $dist[$i];
    $acum[$i+1] = $acum[$i];   
    print outfile "$limit $acum[$i]\n";
}


close(outfile);
```

Comment: Please tell us what programming languages you do understand.  We can use concepts from the languages you do understand to help with explaining this program.

Comment: c++ but I cannot understand something like $val

Comment: `$val` is a scalar value ( meaning it holds one item ). It can hold one number (int or float), a string, or a reference to some other variable or code reference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first a quick discussion of ARGV.  This is just like char **argv that is used in the main() declaration of C programs

ARGV in perl is declared implicitly as an array.  In perl we refer to whole arrays like this

```
@ARGV
```

and to the size of the array like this

```
$#ARGV
```

and to individual elements in the array like this

```
$ARGV[0]
```

arrays are indexed from zero, so `$ARGV[0]` is the first element of the array @ARGV

That's how the command line args for the program are read and that's what all the references to ARGV are concerned with

next item

```
open(infile,"$ARGV[0]") || die "Couldn't open $ARGV[0] for reading.\n";
open(outfile,">$ARGV[2]") || die "Couldn't open $ARGV[2] for writing.\n";
```

This is self documenting, given what I've just discussed with ARGV.  This makes a pair of filehandles for input and output.  Variables mentioned in double quotes `"` are interpolated to their values.  So if `$ARGV[0]` is "filename1.txt" then `"ARGV[0]"` compiles as "filename1.txt"

In perl, as well as arrays, simple single value variables (called scalars) are also allowed

`$x=1` is similar to `x=1` in C.

In perl however, strings can be assigned without allocation of memory.  This is automatic.  String "type" variables can trivially be converted to numbers.  A simple variable can start off as a number then be converted to a string and then back to a number all automatically depending on the context.  Also it is not compulsary to declare variables!  In C you'd have to say `int x` to declare it, this is not strictly enforced in perl

Next bit of code

```
for ($i=0; $i< 100 / $ARGV[1]; $i++) {
    $dist[$i] = 0;
    $acum[$i] = 0;
}
```

This is exactly as it would be in C except that the variables have some extra $ signs in front and there is no need to declare the size of the arrays @dist and @acum, or their type

Next bit to consider

```
while (<infile>) {

    if ($_ > $max) {
    $max=$_;
    }    
}
```

`infile` is a file handle and the construct `<infile>` reads one line from the file.  But you will note that it isn't clear to *where* in the perl program the data is read.
The perl trick used here is that there is a default variable that contains the last read line.  The variable is `$_`.  So all this loop is doing is looking for the max value in the file.

I'll skip a bit now and go right to the end

```
for ($i=0; $i< $ARGV[1]; $i++) {
    $limit = ($i+1) * $intsize;
    $acum[$i]+= $dist[$i];
    $acum[$i+1] = $acum[$i];   
    print outfile "$limit $acum[$i]\n";
}
```

This is a loop doing operations on the array `@acum` similar to the `for` loop above
The print line writes to the output handle.  The variables are interpolated as mentioned above.

Hope this helps your understanding

Comment: Declaring variables is strictly enforced if you add `use strict;` to the beginning of the file. It is also **highly** recommended that you do add [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) (and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html)) to the beginning of any Perl file.

Comment: `$#ARGV` is not the size but the last index. `scalar @ARGV` or scalar context comparisons will get the size.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have got is not written very well. Here you are a revised version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# pragmas
use strict;
use warnings;

# read command line arguments
if ($#ARGV < 2 || $#ARGV > 3) {
    print "Usage: perl $0 <input file> <num intervals> <output file> [<interval size>]\n";
    exit 1;
}
my ($input_file, $num_intervals, $output_file, $interval_size) = @ARGV;

# find interval_size if not specified
unless (defined $interval_size) {
    my $max = 0;
    process($input_file, sub { $max = $_[0] if $_[0] > $max });
    $interval_size = $max / $num_intervals;
}

# fill dist array
my @dist;
process($input_file, sub {
    my $q = $_[0] / $interval_size;
    my $val = int $q;
    $dist[$val == $q ? $val - 1 : $val]++;
});

open my $fh_out, '>', $output_file
    or die "cannot open (write) file '$output_file': $!\n";

# fill acum and generate output
my @acum;
for (0 .. $num_intervals - 1) {
    my $limit = ($_ + 1) * $interval_size;
    $acum[$_] += $dist[$_];
    $acum[$_+1] = $acum[$_];
    print $fh_out "$limit $acum[$_]\n";
}

close $fh_out;

#
# process 'filename', sub {
#     my ($line) = @_;
#     # do something with $line, it is chomped
# };
#
sub process {
    my ($file, $code) = @_;

    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or die "cannot open (read) file '$file': $!\n";

    local $_;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        $code->($_);
    }

    close $fh;
}
```

regards, Matthias

PS: I did not test the code but perl -c is OK with it.